# Java String Conversion to Binary

Tags: java, converters

I need to write a converter in Java where it asks the user for an *input*, *sourceAlphabet* and *targetAlphabet*). The code should then provide an answer which has converted the *sourceAlphabet* to the *targetAlphabet*.

Alphabets should be given in the form:

-"0123456789" (Base 10),

-"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" (Alphabet),

-"0123456789ABCDEF" (Hexadecimal), etc.

Each alphabet value is a single unique ASCII character.

These are some sample inputs and answers I am looking for from the code:

```
convert("129","0123456789","01") === "10000001"
convert("FF","0123456789ABCDEF","0123456789") === "255"
convert("svip","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","0123456789ABCDEF") === "50C23"
```

Any help in getting me started on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: you are basically converting from one base to another, and then mapping the digits in the base to the alphabet given.

Comment: Thank you - yeah I understand what I need to do - I just haven't coded in Java for a very long time so I am unsure how to start the coding.

Comment: And what did you tried? you want someone to write the code for you, or you have an specific problem with your implementation?

Comment: If someone could write the code for that would be great. However, I will more than happily accept some examples/good starting points to get me off in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the wrong place to ask for people to write code from scratch for a use-case. Have a quick peek at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info. You might try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour for more conceptual questions, or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour for peer review of your code.

Comment: I don't think anyone's going to write the code for you.  If you don't have any idea how to convert numbers to or from a base, http://www.mathsisfun.com/base-conversion-method.html might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, create a function that converts from decimal to hexadecimal.

The best tools to help you do this will be the modulo operator (x % y) and the division operator (x / y). Modulo (or mod) gives you the remainder, so if you imagine have a number like 24, 24 % 16 = 8, while 24 / 16 = 1. Notice that if I had 31 % 16, I would receive 15.

With those tools, you can operate on the input decimal and repeatedly mod by the base over the number to get the remainder, and then set the decimal equal to itself divided by the base.

For example.

Step 1.
Decimal : 31
String : ""
Base : 16

31 % 16 = 15
31 / 16 = 1

Step 2 
Decimal : 1
String : "E"
Base : 16

1 % 16 = 1
1 / 16 = 1

Step 3
Decimal : 0
String :"1E"
Base : 16

Fin

Hope that helps.